# Using the `where T : SOMETHING` construct in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Just found a bit of code someone here had written to access some DB Entities...

```
public static OurCustomObject GetOurCustomObject(int primaryKey)
{
    return GetOurCustomObject<int>(primaryKey, "usp_GetOurCustomObjectByID");
}

public static OurCustomObject GetOurCustomObject(Guid uniqueIdent)
{
    return GetOurCustomObject<Guid>(uniqueIdent, "usp_GetOurCustomObjectByGUID");
}

private static OurCustomObject<T>(T identifier, string sproc)
{

    if((T != typeof(int)) && (T == typeof(Guid)))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Identifier must be a string or an int");
    }

    //ADO.NET Code to make DB Call with supplied sproc.
}
```

Theres just something about it that doesn't seem very `generic`. The fact that the
sprocs are passed into the inner method feels ugly. but the only way I can see around that is to have an if/else in the private method along the lines of

```
if(type == int)
    sproc = "GetByID";
else if (type == Guid)
    sproc = "GetByGUID";
```

Also the exception throwing looks ugly as well... is there anyway to use a where T : clause

e.g.

```
private static OurCustomObject<T>(T identifier) where T : int OR Guid
```

Any suggestions on how to clean this up a little.

Comment: What are you using "T" for in the body of the method?

Comment: That's just it, it wasn't being specifically used. There was the typeof(T) == typeof(int) check, and then after that they were just executing the SPROC using a SQL Helper call and just passing the identifier as a parameter. which is why i just thought the usage felt a little forced

Comment: Then I agree with you that this seems like a bad design. The purpose of generic methods is to be, well, GENERIC. A "generic" that can only be two things isn't very generic.  If you're not using T for anything else then the only thing you can possibly be using "identifier" -- an unconstrained T -- for in the body is as a System.Object. Why not eliminate the genericity altogether and just make "identifier" an object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't specify a constraint which says "it's one of these two", no.

What you *could* do is:

```
Dictionary<Type, string> StoredProcedureByType = new Dictionary<Type, string>
{
    { typeof(Guid), "GetByGUID" },
    { typeof(int), "GetByID" }
};
```

Then use:

```
string sproc;
if (!StoredProcedureByType.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out sproc))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type: " + typeof(T).Name);
}
```

This is probably overkill for just a couple of types, but it scales well if you have a lot of types involved.

Given that both types are value types, you can make it a *bit* more robust with a constraint of:

```
where T : struct
```

but that will still allow `byte` etc.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided looks reasonably fine to me, because `private static OurCustomObject<T>(T identifier, string sproc)` is private. I would even drop the exception checking from this method, because again  - its private, so this class controls what gets passed to the method. The if statement would be rather horrible and over-engineered.

Answer (score 1):

The neatest thing to do is probably doing something like this:

```
public interface IPrimaryKey 
{
}

public class PrimaryGuidKey(Guid key) : IPrimaryKey 

public class PrimaryIntegerKey(int key) : IPrimaryKey

private static OurCustomObject<T>(T identifier) where T : IPrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for such a where clause to limit the type parameter in that way (unfortunatelly).

In this case, you might find that passing `identifier` as an object, and *not* using generics is actually cleaner (when I needed something similar, that is what I ended up doing: seemed to be the least worst approach).

This is an area that C# is weak, being neither a dynamic language or being able to specialise the template (C++ like, only providing implementations for T = int and T = Guid).

Adendum: In this case I would likely stick with the overload, but change the type check to an `Assert` as that is a private helper method.

Comment: Generic types are not templates, and are not intended to be.  One could make the argument that C++ templates are "weak" because, unlike generic types, they cannot be constructed with a new type argument after the template has been compiled into a library. But that would be a silly argument; the simple fact is that generics and templates, though superficially similar textually, actually have very different semantics and solve different problems.

Comment: @Eric: True, but that does not stop there being times when a specialisation would really help.